# SQL - add Char(10) line feed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

(MS SQL only 2008R2)
I would like to know how to add a `Char(10)` line feed before and after each occurrence of a `timestamp (##:##:##)` in a string.

So, if I have a string of `"askdfjaksdfja asfd kj 03:56:34 sdfas 09:56:12 sdfa sd sss dg"`, then I want all of the `##:##:##` have a line feed place right before and after each one.

The `timestamps` could be any time and the string could be anything.

Thank you!

Comment: Vanilla TSQL is not really the best choice for string parsing (slow, no regex, etc). Do you have any other programming tools available?

Comment: No, not really.  This is for a one time (maybe a couple times) query on a small amount of data.

Comment: @StingyJack Not really the same

Comment: Kind of the same, the pattern you are looking for is ":__:", where the underscores are any two single characters between the two colons. You would then count two index to right and insert your Char(10). Really though, consider hand parsing or loading it into Excel if its a small one time job.

Comment: Well, it's small for me, but not that small enough to do it by hand.  It's thousands of records.

Comment: @StingyJack that pattern is incorrect. It needs to be numbers, not any two characters, and needs to match at the end of the time, not after just one section of it.

Comment: @ErikE - Its a Quick and Dirty for a one off, so two underscores surrounded by colons is probably going to be enough, and I said "to the right" meaning the end of the time.

Comment: I just have a hard time with using patterns that might match the wrong input. What if there is already a line feed in the desired position(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One time thing?  Ok... heres a shot. You can wrap this in a function and use it in your table query. You might have to tweak this depending on how many edge cases you want to support. You can do so by altering the dataset that is staged in @replace.

```
set nocount on;

declare @string varchar(max);
set @string = 'askdfjaksdfja asfd kj 03:56:34 sdfas 09:56:12 sdfa sd sss dg 42test x77:xx ';

declare @replace table (this char(4), that char(4));

with digits(NN) as
(
    select top 60 right('0'+cast(row_number() over(order by object_id)-1 as varchar), 2)
    from sys.all_columns --use your numbers table
)
insert into @replace
    --replace " NN:" with "char(10)+NN:"
    select  space(1)+NN+':',
            char(10)+NN+':'
    from    digits
    union all
    --replace ":NN " with ":NN+char(10)" 
    select  ':'+NN+space(1),
            ':'+NN+char(10)
    from    digits;

select  @string = replace(@string, this, that)
from    @replace
where   charindex(this, @string)>0;

select @string
```

Comment: I added a union all of '00' to the query so that I would work when there was a '00' in the string.